# In regular expression, how to match a string with optional string

Tags: regex

My regular expression is

```
\/(.*)\/(((?:opt1)?)((?:\/opt2)?)((?:\/opt3))?)?\/data\/(.*)
```

In the above expression, I'm considering **/opt1/opt2/opt3** as optional where all can be present or either one or two.

My desired output is below strings should match

- /main/opt1/opt2/opt3/data/a.txt
- /main/opt1/data/b.txt
- /main/opt2/data/c.txt
- /main/opt2/opt3/data/d.txt
- /main/opt3/data/e.txt
- /main/data/ee.txt

But only **/main/opt1/data/sample.txt** is getting matched. Also below string's should not match

- /main/data1/f.txt
- /main/opt1/data1/g.txt
- /main/opt2/h.txt

What is the problem here. Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @heemayl - edited my question, my expected output is given regex should match the strings which i listed out there

Comment: a much **[simpler](https://regex101.com/r/fR8qC5/4)** version

Comment: What about `/main/opt1/data/some words`, `/main/opt1/data`, `/main/opt1/data/`, `/main/opt3/opt2/opt2/data/a.txt` or `/anothermain/opt1/data/b.txt`? Should they match or not?

Comment: @Andrew - only `/main/opt1/data/some words` should match, not others

Comment: Check that I later added `opt3/opt2/...`. Does that order matter? Also, what about `/opt1/opt1/opt1`?

Comment: @Andrew - no order doesnt matter

Comment: What about repetition of the same folder name, like the second example of my previous comment?

Comment: @Andrew no repetition of same name

Comment: I think allowing different order but no repetitions will be tricky via a regex.

Comment: @Andrew exactly..we require some PHP script to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler way will be to use

```
^\/[^\/]*(?:\/opt[123])*\/data\/.+$
   <---->
Replace with main
  if necessary
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR8qC5/6)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Starting of string
\/ #Match / literally
[^\/]* #Match anything except /
(?:\/opt[123])* #Match opt followed by 1, 2 or 3
\/ #Match / literally
data #Match data literally
\/ #Match / literally
.+ #From last / to end of string
$ #End of string
```

You can also define range if required for only 0 to 3 occurence

```
^\/[^\/]*(?:\/opt[123]){0,3}\/data\/.+$
```

If the order matters, then you can use

```
^\/main(?:\/opt1)?(?:\/opt2)?(?:\/opt3)?\/data\/.+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR8qC5/5)**

Comment: I don't know if it's a possible string, but this also matches `/main/opt1/data/b.txt and some more words`.

Comment: @Andrew well I didn't modified the last part because OP is also using `.*` in last

Comment: What if you remove the `?:`?

Comment: @Andrew well that will create a capturing group and store the data which may not be necessary for OP

Comment: `main` seems to be mandatory, and this regex would match `/blabla/data/blabla`.

Comment: LOL, yeah. And also, opt# shouldn't be repeated.

Comment: @Andrew that part was mentioned in comment..didn't saw it

Answer (score 1):

This simple regular expression seems to do the trick, it works fine with your test strings:

```
\/main(\/opt[123])*\/data\/.+
```

If your input string won't contain any other character, you can also add the anchors to specify begin and end:

```
^\/main(\/opt[123])*\/data\/.+$
```